# Template js doesn't work after CKEditor enable/disable

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular8, ckeditor4.x

In my template I was integrate ckeditor4 (^4.15.0), and I have logic that user can enable/disable editor, after disable editor template's tab navigation doesn't work.

**StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-medium-editor-example-owkegm

**Video**:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37144283/133139868-445a64af-b5c1-4cdd-b82a-bab2dd1c8d2d.mp4

**Description of video:**
At the start editor is enabled (places where there are dashed lines these are editable areas, and editor can work), and I do not click any area and just disable editor, after that I click on tabs and they works, but after I again enable editor, click on the one of tabs, editor starts working, and again I do not change anything, just activate editor on this tab area, and after again disable editor and after that when I click on tabs they do not work, it's strange because in Inspect element I see that nothing changed in html part also (e.g. deleting any attribute or something like this).

*P.S. If I do click on other area (not on tab) editors activate and after that disable editor, tabs works perfectly, I'm getting this issue only in case when I do click on tab navigation area.*

Comment: if you look in inspector, you will see that after editing your old elements are replaced with new ones. And your code in `index.html` won't work.

Comment: @Alexy in this case how can I refresh my js code in order to continue work? or it is impossible?

Comment: You have many ways to solve this, one of them is recall `init()` function

Comment: @Alexy You know it's just a demo and your solution is working, but what if it's written in the lib, and there are many methods, I can't recall all js methods)) There is any way to refresh js file or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by remove scripts from the template and add them back to the template. Thanks!